# Getting com port signal for netbeans using Arduino

Tags: java, netbeans, arduino

I am doing an Arduino project using NetBeans and Arduino IDE. In that time I was felt with the problem. I am using my code to get signal from Arduino board using a variable resistor for getting various signal for my program.

I am attaching my NetBeans source code.

```
package hirikattaproject;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class HirikattaProject {
    static SerialPort chosenPort;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create confugaration window
        JFrame window=new JFrame();
        window.setTitle("Sensor value");
        window.setSize(600,400);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //create a dropdown list and button
        JComboBox<String> portList=new JComboBox<String>();
        JButton connectionButton=new JButton("connect");
        JPanel topPanel=new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(portList);
        topPanel.add(connectionButton);
        window.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //populate the dropdown list
        SerialPort[] portNames=SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for(int i=0;i<portNames.length;i++){
            portList.addItem(portNames[i].getSystemPortName());
        }

        //create line Graph
        XYSeries series=new XYSeries("Sensor Reading");
        XYSeriesCollection dataset=new XYSeriesCollection();
        JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("SensorReading", "time(Second)", "Reading", dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
        window.add(new ChartPanel(chart),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //configure the connection button and use another thread to listen for data
        connectionButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                if(connectionButton.getText().equals("connect")){
                    //attempt to coonect serial port
                    chosenPort =SerialPort.getCommPort(portList.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    chosenPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
                    if(chosenPort.openPort()){
                        connectionButton.setText("Disconnect");
                        portList.setEnabled(false);                       
                    }
                    //create new threed that listens for incoming text and populates the graph
                    Thread thread=new Thread(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(chosenPort.getInputStream());
                                int x=0;
                                while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                                        String line=scanner.nextLine();
                                        int number =Integer.parseInt(line);
                                        series.add(x++,number);
                                }

                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
                }else{
                //disconnect serial port
                    chosenPort.closePort();
                    portList.setEnabled(true);
                    connectionButton.setText("connect");
                }

            }
        });

        //show window
        window.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

and Arduino source code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int s=  analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(s);
}`.
```

I am adding the Arduino circuit image and also error image

[image: error photo]

I am also adding this image, I think that may be the error.

[image: My thinking error].

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem are the librarys.

Copy the librarys
rxtxSerial.dll
rxtxParallel.dll

In Folders

C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxx\bin\

C:\Program Files\Java\jrexxx\bin\

And attach the RXTXcomm.jar in the project

The librarys has in
http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java